# How to support an async callback with timeout in swift actor

Tags: swift, async-await, actor, swift-concurrency

I have a mix of async/await (Actors) running "legacy" code (Process Pipes and callback blocks). I have a situation similar to this where my actor's function returns a value, while also storing a deferred callback once some work is completed ( actor should not block while waiting for the work to complete, the actor purpose is only to support id generation and internal updates which need to be threadsafe). Ideally I would like to structure the callback to also be ergonomic as an "async" variant
I am using an actor for thread safety. One of the async functions stores a callback which is called once the work is completed or once a timeout has occurred.
Currently getting a deadlock as well as "ugly" nesting.

```
typealias Block = (String?) async -> Void // do I need the async keyword here necessarily?

actor Processor {
  let id = Int
  var callbacks = [Int:Block]()
  let process : Process // external process which communicates of stdin/stdout
  init(processPath: String) async throws {
    process = Process()
    process.launchPath = processPath
    process.standardInput = Pipe()
    process.standardOutput = Pipe()
    (process.standardOutput as! Pipe).fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = {[weak self] handler in
       // does not support async/await directly, wrapping in a task, perhaps better mechanism?
       Task {[weak self] in
          await self?.handleOutput(data: handler.availableData)
       }
    }
  }

  struct Result: Codable { 
     id: Int ,
     output: String
  }
  func handleOutput(data: Data) {
     if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data),
            let id = decoded.id ,
            let callback = pop(id: id) {
            await callback(decoded.output) // call the block, this time with real value vs when there was a timeout
        }
  }
  func work(text: String, completion: @escaping Block) async -> WorkArgs {
     id += 1 // increment the running id
     // store the callback
     callbacks[id] = completion
     // timeout if the result doesn't come back in a reasonable amount of time. 
     // I will perform a check after 1 second, and pop the callback if needed
     // problematic here..., how to wait while also not blocking this function
     Task { [weak self] in
       // invalidate if needed
       try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
       // dead lock here:
       if let bl = await self?.pop(id: id) {
            print("invalidated the task \(id)")
            await bl(nil)
       }
     }
     // call out to the external process with this convention, it will run async and print a result with the same id
     let command = "\(id) \(text)\n"
     let d = command(using: .utf8)

     try! (process.standardInput as! Pipe).fileHandleForWriting.write(contentsOf: d)
     
  }
  // pop this callback
  func pop(id: Int) -> Block? {
        return callbacks.removeValue(forKey: id)
  }
}

struct WorkArgs {
  let id: Int
  let date: Date
}

actor IdGen {
    private var id : Int64 = 0
    func next() -> Int64 {
        id += 1
        return id
    }
}

actor CallbackActor {
var pendingCallbacks = [Int: (String) -> Void]()
    func push(_ key: Int, block: @escaping  (String) -> Void) {
        pendingCallbacks[key] = block
    }
    func pop(_ key: Int64) -> AutoCompleteBlock? {
        return pendingCallbacks.removeValue(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before I get to the timeout question, we should probably talk about how to wrap the `Process` within Swift concurrency.

- One pattern would be to use `AsyncSequence` (i.e., an `AsyncStream`) for `stdout`:

  ```swift
  actor ProcessWithStream {
      private let process = Process()
      private let stdin = Pipe()
      private let stdout = Pipe()
      private let stderr = Pipe()
      private var buffer = Data()

      init(url: URL) {
          process.standardInput = stdin
          process.standardOutput = stdout
          process.standardError = stderr
          process.executableURL = url
      }

      func start() throws {
          try process.run()
      }

      func terminate() {
          process.terminate()
      }

      func send(_ string: String) {
          guard let data = "\(string)\n".data(using: .utf8) else { return }
          stdin.fileHandleForWriting.write(data)
      }

      func stream() -> AsyncStream<Data> {
          AsyncStream(Data.self) { continuation in
              stdout.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { handler in
                  continuation.yield(handler.availableData)
              }
              process.terminationHandler = { handler in
                  continuation.finish()
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  Then you can `for await` that stream:

  ```swift
  let process = ProcessWithStream(url: url)

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      Task {
          try await startStream()
          print("done")
      }
  }

  @IBAction func didTapSend(_ sender: Any) {
      let string = textField.stringValue
      Task {
          await process.send(string)
      }
      textField.stringValue = ""
  }

  func startStream() async throws {
      try await process.start()
      let stream = await process.stream()

      for await data in stream {
          if let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
              print(string, terminator: "")
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  This is a simple approach. And it looks fine (because I am printing responses without a terminator).

  But one needs to be careful because `readabilityHandler` will not always be called with the full `Data` of some particular output. It might be broken up or split across separate calls to the `reachabilityhandler`.
- Another pattern would be to use `lines`, which avoids the problem of `reachabilityHandler` possibly being called multiple times for a given output:

  ```swift
  actor ProcessWithLines {
      private let process = Process()
      private let stdin = Pipe()
      private let stdout = Pipe()
      private let stderr = Pipe()
      private var buffer = Data()
      private(set) var lines: AsyncLineSequence<FileHandle.AsyncBytes>?

      init(url: URL) {
          process.standardInput = stdin
          process.standardOutput = stdout
          process.standardError = stderr
          process.executableURL = url
      }

      func start() throws {
          lines = stdout.fileHandleForReading.bytes.lines
          try process.run()
      }

      func terminate() {
          process.terminate()
      }

      func send(_ string: String) {
          guard let data = "\(string)\n".data(using: .utf8) else { return }
          stdin.fileHandleForWriting.write(data)
      }
  }
  ```

  Then you can do:

  ```swift
  let process = ProcessWithLines(url: url)

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      Task {
          try await startStream()
          print("done")
      }
  }

  @IBAction func didTapSend(_ sender: Any) {
      let string = textField.stringValue
      Task {
          await process.send(string)
      }
      textField.stringValue = ""
  }

  func startStream() async throws {
      try await process.start()
      guard let lines = await process.lines else { return }

      for try await line in lines {
          print(line)
      }
  }
  ```

  This avoids the breaking of responses mid-line.

---

You asked:

> How to support ... timeout in swift actor

The pattern is to wrap the request in a `Task`, and then start a separate task that will cancel that prior task after a `Task.sleep` interval.

But this is going to be surprisingly complicated in this case, because you have to coordinate that with the separate `Process` which will otherwise still proceed, unaware that the `Task` has been canceled. That can theoretically lead to problems (e.g., the process gets backlogged, etc.).

I would advise integrating the timeout logic in the app invoked by the `Process`, rather than trying to have the caller handle that. It can be done (e.g. maybe write the process app to capture and handle `SIGINT` and then the caller can call [`interrupt`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process/1410874-interrupt) on the `Process`). But it is going to be complicated and, most likely, brittle.

Comment: thank you for the comprehensive explanation!